# PDE Tools (Create Ant build file) not generating ant script(build.xml)

Tags: apache, ant, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have created one plugin project "com.example.first" and one plugin feature project "com.example.first.feature" for the plugin.

I am  able to generate build.xml(ant build file) for "com.exilant.first"  by following below steps:

right click on build.properties---->Plug-in-tools--->Create Ant build file.

I am following same steps to create build.xml for "com.exilant.first.feature" (feature project) but after clicking 'Create Ant build file' noting is happening(not generating build.xml).

Please help!

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory you will probably see the message:

```
Could not find valid manifest file to create ant build file
```

The 'create Ant Build file' will only work if it finds a META-INF/MANIFEST.MF in the project. However feature projects don't normally have these so I don't understand what this code is trying to do.

Try using 'File > Export > Plug-in Development > Deployable features'. On the 'Options' tab you can ask it to save the Ant script it generates.

Comment: thank you greg for your quick and suitable response... actually  I have created feature project to distribute my plugin.I am new to plugin development.I just followed some document. Please suggest me how can I solve this issue.Can I add manifest file explicitly?I need to generate the ant script for this feature project.How Can I do it?

Comment: This, I have already tried but problem is that when i build using the generated build.xml it is not generating p2 repository(artifact.jar and content.jar) . I  selected 'generate p2  repository' while creating build.xml.how can i generate p2 repository?

Comment: **The generated ANT script is using pde.exportfeature task that is not synchronous so while pubish feature and bundle task(p2.publish.featuresAndBundles) that is dependent on the output of pde.exportfeature task , is not generating output as expected. So I used a  trick,copied matadata file from plugin project into plugin feature project and customized it for the feature project  and then I was able to generate build file from PDE tools using: build.properties---->Plug-in-tools--->Create Ant build file.this trick worked perfectly fine.**